# Rails .update_attribute not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I notice this question pops up a lot, but after trying several recommended solutions I found I still can't figure out what is wrong. I have a model called sample and a user model as well. When a sample is approved the hours on the sample are supposed to be added to the users total hours, but the users value is never updated. Each user has a unique email which is stored in the sample when it is submitted for approval. I checked in the database to make sure it wasn't an issue with accessing the value, and no error is being thrown so I am not really sure what is happening. I'm pretty new to ruby and rails so any help is appreciated. My samples_controller.rb contains the function:

```
  def approve
    @sample = Sample.find(params[:id])
    @sample.update(sample_status:1)
    @user = User.find(Sample.email)
    hours_update = @user.hours + @sample.volunteer_hours
    @user.update_attributes(:hours, hours_update)
    redirect_to samples_adminsamples_path
  end
```

Edit: thanks for the help everyone, turns out I needed to use the command

```
@user = User.find_by(email: @sample.email)
```

in order to get the proper user.

Comment: Can you tell me what value you get in hours update and what is the data type of hours field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please give some more data like db structure of Sample and User tables.

From the limited information, I think the line number 4 (`@user = User.find(Sample.email)`) is the problem.

`.find()` tries to query the DB on `id` and `Sample.email` would be giving user's email and not the `id` of the corresponding user in db.

I am also guessing that in your controller, you are suppressing the thrown exception some where using `begin-rescue` block because `.find()` throws `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception if it fails to find the resource.

Alternatively, if it is fetching the user correctly, you can also try `update_column` to update the values.

Comment: This was the issue, I needed to use `@user = User.find_by(email: @sample.email)` to get the right user, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect format for [**`update_attributes`**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attributes)

It should be

```
@user.update_attributes(hours: hours_update)
```

or

```
@user.update_attribute(:hours, hours_update)
```

> **NOTE: `update_attribute` doesn't triggers the callbacks**

Comment: I tried both formats you recommended and am still having the same issue, no error messages or any other clues.

Comment: Acording to https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute, when use update_attribute, "Validation is skipped, Callbacks are invoked".